# Batch script is not getting executed when called by Start-Process Cmdlet

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, batch-file

I have a strange issue on a Windows Server 2012 R2 here that just does not make any sense to me at all.

I've got a PowerShell script that basically has the following structure:

```
Function Something-Different
{
    [...]
}

Function Start-Some-Batch
{
    Start-Process "K:\Path\To\Batch.cmd" 
}

Function Something-Else
{
    [...]
}

Something-Different
Start-Some-Batch
Something-Else
```

However the batch file `K:\Path\To\Batch.cmd` never ever gets executed!

**Some more information and facts:**

- All actions are performed with the same domain user
- PowerShell version is 4.0
- The batch file can be executed without any issues when double-clicking it within Windows Explorer
- The PowerShell script does not provide any error output
- Executing `Start-Process "K:\Path\To\Batch.cmd"`directly from a PowerShell console does also not provide any output nor does it kick of the batch script
- `$error[0]` is empty after the execution
- The function `Something-Else` is executing just fine (which means `Start-Some-Batch` is not preventing the PS-script from finishing its execution)
- Running the PowerShell script elevated does not change a thing
- Calling the batch script from a cmd.exe prompt does also not start it (elevated or not)
- I am suspecting any of the hundred `Security Settings` that come via group-policy

What could cause such a strange behaviour? I am running out of ideas here.

Comment: "Calling the batch script from a cmd.exe prompt does also not start it" -- There's your problem. What's the .cmd file's real name? What are its contents?  What are the relevant security settings applied?

Comment: Have you tried renaming it to .bat instead of .cmd?

Comment: Have you tried `Start-Process cmd "/c K:\Path\To\Batch.cmd"`?

Comment: Thanks all for replying. I managed to solve this by supplying the `-WorkingDirectory` parameter. Sometimes I miss the forest for the trees...

Comment: @Matze I curious how that resolves the issue if you're unable to run the batch file from a `cmd` prompt. Are you unable to run it in `cmd` because you're not in the same directory as the .cmd file?  You should post your resolution as an answer below so you can [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). [Answering your own questions is strongly encouraged](http://serverfault.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Here is what works for me, using Powershell v4.

`PS C:\Scripts> Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList "/c 1.cmd" -WorkingDirectory c:\test4`

Where `1.cmd` lives in `c:\test4`

Answer (score 0):

The best workaround I've found for this issue comes from an example by Chocolatey for their `Start-ChocolateyProcessAsAdmin` method.

```
$somePath = "C:\Path with Spaces" # Like $env:ProgramFiles
$batFile= "$someVar\myfile.bat"
Start-Process -ArgumentList "/c `'$batFile`'" -FilePath 'cmd.exe'
```

Note it can be single or double quotes inside the `-ArgumentList`, they just need escaped when inside other quotes.

This works because the first "pass" where PowerShell evaluates the Start-Process line will resolve the $batFile to it's correct value, it then passes the `/c 'C:\Path with Spaces\myfile.bat'` to the `cmd.exe`.